# Swift FMDB modifiers

Tags: swift, fmdb

where are the modifiers for SQL FMDB described ?
In particular, how do I place a quote within a string I wish to insert. Such as I wish to insert name "Mac's Place" into the database ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `executeUpdate` with `?` placeholders in the SQL and then supply the parameters as arguments in the array, you don't have to quote the special characters in the string. For example, you can:

```
if !db.executeUpdate("insert into restaurants (name) values (?)", withArgumentsInArray: ["Mac's Place"]) {
    println(db.lastErrorMessage())
}
```

Comment: will try it out.  Was using the 'values' option in the insert command